# Setting sockopt for client socket returned from accept()

Tags: c, sockets, setsockopt

I'm trying to set socket options for a client socket returned from the `accept()` function. But they are not getting set correctly.

My aim is to time out the client after a particular time of inactivity. But the server should still be able to accept other client connections.

Below is my code where I set the socket option.  Can you please suggest what is wrong?

```
while ((new_sock_fd = accept(socket_fd, (struct sockaddr *) &cli_addr, &clilen)) > 0)
{
    if (new_sock_fd < 0)
        printf("Accept Error");
    else
    {
        struct timeval timeout;      
        timeout.tv_sec = 10;
        timeout.tv_usec = 0;
        if (setsockopt(new_sock_fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVTIMEO, (char *)&timeout, sizeof(timeout)) < 0)
            error("setsockopt failed\n");
        if (setsockopt(new_sock_fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_SNDTIMEO, (char *)&timeout, sizeof(timeout)) < 0)
            error("setsockopt failed\n");
        pthread_create(&thread, NULL, client_handler, (void *) (intptr_t)new_sock_fd); //intptr_t is big enough to hold the integer prt
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you know the options are not being set? Is `setsockopt()` failing with an error? Does `getsocktop()` return values you are not expecting? Does the socket simply behave differently than expected? If so, how? What platform is this code running on? On most platforms `SO_RCVTIMEO` and `SO_SENDTIMEO` do indeed take a `timeval` struct as input. But on Windows, they take a `DWORD` instead.

Comment: Also, your `Accept Error` message will never be reported, since your loop only enters the loop body when `new_socket_fd > 0`.  If you want to do error handling on `accept()`, you should move it inside the loop instead.

Answer (score 1):

> My aim is to time out the client after a particular time of
>   inactivity. [...] can you please suggest what when wrong..?

I suspect what's wrong is that you're misunderstanding what SO_RCVTIMEO and SO_SNDTIMEO are intended to do.  From the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/7/socket):

> SO_RCVTIMEO and SO_SNDTIMEO Specify the receiving or sending timeouts
>   until reporting an error. The argument is a struct timeval. If an
>   input or output function blocks for this period of time, and data has
>   been sent or received, the return value of that function will be the
>   amount of data transferred; if no data has been transferred and the
>   timeout has been reached then -1 is returned with errno set to EAGAIN
>   or EWOULDBLOCK, or EINPROGRESS (for connect(2)) just as if the socket
>   was specified to be nonblocking. If the timeout is set to zero (the
>   default) then the operation will never timeout.

... but it sounds like what you want is for the TCP connection be automatically closed after a certain amount of time with no traffic on the TCP connection, which is not the same thing as forcing a call to send() or recv() to return after a specified amount of time.

If what you are looking for is a mechanism to close an idle TCP connection, you can implement that yourself by recording the current time whenever data is sent or received on the socket.  At a later time (e.g. after send() or recv() times out), you can subtract your recorded last-traffic-seen-at-time from the current time; if the difference is greater than your idle-timeout value, call close() on the socket yourself.

Comment: Or, simply use `select()` or `epoll()` to implement the timeout instead.  Put the socket into non-blocking mode, and then 1) before reading, poll for readability with timeout; 2) if sending fails with ` EAGAIN` or `EWOULDBLOCK`, poll for writability with timeout. If either operation times out, close the connection.